# Contributing rosdep rules for Debian

Tags: pcl, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have successfully installed ROS Fuerte on a Debian Squeeze machine. Along the way, I ran into problems with unmet dependencies/undefined build rules, similar to those described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/40131/definition-for-ros-packages-on-debian-squeeze/) and [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/33002/rosdep-install-a-fails-on-debian-sqeeze/), which required some manual tweaking to resolve. A very useful post was the answer to [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/33002/rosdep-install-a-fails-on-debian-sqeeze/) question by jamuraa.

I have read the [howto on Contributing rosdep rules](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html), and I would like to contribute the necessary rules, so that ROS can be built automatically on Debian through rosdep/rosmake, but I'm confused on how to do it for this particular case. The two major dependencies that currently break `rosdep install -a` are flann and pcl. Both of these dependencies are not defined in standard rosdep.yaml files, but in [this gbpdistro file](https://raw.github.com/ros/rosdistro/master/releases/fuerte.yaml). Searching the wiki yields only one reference to gbpdistro files, in [rep 125](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0125.html#gbpdistro-files).

So, my question is, what is the right way to contribute rosdep rules for installing flann and pcl on Debian, and share this with the community? Should I:

a) create a new yaml file for Debian and override the gpbdistro file, similar to the gentoo.yaml and osx-homebrew.yaml?

b) modify the gpbdistro file in some way?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44070/contributing-rosdep-rules-for-debian/) by [damjan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2702/damjan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 446 on 2012-09-18

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the similarities between Ubuntu and Debian rules.  It's probably easier to keep them side by side, most of the time they will be the same.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0